# How do I get MySQL data into an array within the Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, google-maps-api-3

**Tech Used:**

- Node.js npm
- MySQL npm

**Tried:**

- Using a return statement
- Creating a function that calls both functions
- Nesting the functions
- Globally defining the result

**Project goals:**

[X] To load in a mysql database (see following code)

```
let mysql = require('mysql');
let connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password!',
    database: 'database_name',
    multipleStatements: true
});
let sql = `SELECT * FROM table01; SELECT * FROM table02`;
connection.query(sql, (error, results, fields) => {
  if (error) {
    return console.error(error.message);
  }
console.log(results[0]);
console.log(results[1]);
});
```

- Sort the data from the database using Javascript that has yet to be coded
- Apply the values to the Google Maps Javascript API

**Issue:**

- Getting the mysql data into the Google Maps function
  I get an error saying I need to initialize the map first if when I place the connection function within `initMap()`

```
var map;
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: { lat: 47.471, lng: -120.635 },
        zoom: 6.5
    });
}
```

**How do I get the code out of the mySQL query so I can use it?** The most I can get is the data to `console.log()` to my bash terminal. Is there a way to retrieve that logged data from the terminal into Javascript?

**Full code:**

```
let mysql = require('mysql');
    let connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'password!',
        database: 'database_name',
        multipleStatements: true
});
    let sql = `SELECT * FROM table01; SELECT * FROM table02`;
    connection.query(sql, (error, results, fields) => {
      if (error) {
        return console.error(error.message);
      }
    console.log(results[0]);
    console.log(results[1]);
});
var map;
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: { lat: 47.471, lng: -120.635 },
        zoom: 6.5
    });
}
```